# Bitcore Creating a Transaction script variable is missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitcoin, bitcore

I'm using Bitcore to try and make a transaction like in this example:

https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-lib/blob/master/docs/examples.md (Where it says "Create Transaction").

However, I'm having some issues with the "script" part, this is my code:

```
var privateKey = new bitcore.PrivateKey('the private key :P');
var address = bitcore.Address.fromString('1PP4jkxPhJVDP9cEkdbHXvXCiFuiEZTjtb');
var script = bitcore.Script.buildPublicKeyHashOut(address);
```

The console shows me this:

[image]

However, when I use JSON.stringify(script), I get this:

```
{
    "chunks": [{
        "opcodenum": 118
    }, {
        "opcodenum": 169
    }, {
        "buf": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [245, 127, 9, 190, 134, 210, 30, 178, 246, 47, 189, 61, 92, 64, 165, 177, 207, 158, 104, 156
            ]
        },
        "len": 20,
        "opcodenum": 20
    }, {
        "opcodenum": 136
    }, {
        "opcodenum": 172
    }],
    "_network": {
        "name": "live
        net ","
        alias ":"
        mainnet ","
        pubkeyhash ":0,"
        privatekey ":128,"
        scripthash ":5,"
        xpubkey ":
        76067358,
        "xprivkey": 76066276,
        "networkMagic": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [249, 190, 180, 217]
        },
        "port": 8333,
        "dnsSeeds": ["seed.bitcoin.sipa.be", "dnsseed.bluematt.me", "dns
                seed.bitcoin.dashjr.org ","
                seed.bitcoinstats.com ","
                seed.bitnodes.io ","
                bitseed.xf2
                .org "]
    }
}
```

None of those look like the "script" variable that's used to make a transaction on Bitcore's github lib.

Comment: Validate your json with https://jsonlint.com/ it seems like invalid json.

Answer (score 0):

```
var privateKey = new bitcore.PrivateKey('the private key :P');
var address = privateKey.toWIP().toAddress();
var script = bitcore.Script.buildPublicKeyHashOut(address);
```

May be this will help!

You need to create the address with the same private key, and it should be a WIP key. Otherwise it will not work.